# how to get sequence number for dates in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how can I get sequence number for month values

```
[Date]     RN
2016-01-01 1
2016-02-01 2
2016-03-01 3
2016-12-01 12
2016-05-01 5
2016-06-01 6
2016-07-01 7
2016-08-01 8
2016-09-01 9
2016-10-01 10
2016-11-01 11
2016-04-01 4
2016-04-01 4
2016-04-01 4
```

How I can get this one as I have tried with Row_number and Rank()

```
required output 

[Date]     RN
2016-01-01 1
2016-02-01 2
2016-03-01 3
2016-04-01 4
2016-04-01 4
2016-04-01 4
2016-05-01 5
2016-06-01 6
2016-07-01 7
2016-08-01 8
2016-09-01 9
2016-10-01 10
2016-11-01 11
2016-12-01 12
```

Comment: why it got down voted ?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort", e.g. the query you have tried. Nor is it clear. It almost looks like all you need is `order by [Date]`, but since the first table isn't labelled "Sample Input" it's hard to tell.

Comment: @mohan111. Probably because you have not shown any query or work that you have tried (if any). We are here to help fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: Probably because your post shows zero research or effort on your part to solve the issue. You say you tried something, but didnt show the code and incorrect output for anyone to troubleshoot.

Comment: Your output looks like you simply want the month number and nothing to do with a sequence.

Comment: what you mean by effort I have tried with Row_number and Rank functions but got any sequence @HABO

Comment: You may have tried with tea leaves and coconut milk. If you don't include the query you tried, references to documentation you found confusing, links to related SO posts that you explored, ..., then all we have is "I have tried with Row_number and Rank()". That isn't much visible effort or research. Should we have to guess how you applied partitioning and/or ordering to the functions? Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. And respond to Sean Lange's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`. `RANK` will skip the sequence when there is a duplicate

```
Select [Date],DENSE_RANK() OVER(Order by [Date]) as RN
From yourtable
```

Comment: it is not yielding any results @prdp

Comment: @mohan111 What do you mean by *not yielding any results* unless you don't have any records in your table this will always return records because I have not used `Where` clause

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the datepart function.

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, GETUTCDATE())
```

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx